# Weird Link Extraction Behaviour

Tags: python

Python noob here. I'm trying to extract a link, specifically the link to 'all reviews' on an Amazon product page. I get an unexpected result.

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.amazon.com/Ole-Henriksen-Truth-Collagen-         Booster/dp/B000A0ADT8/ref=sr_1_1?s=hpc&ie=UTF8&qid=1342922857&sr=1-1&keywords=truth')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
page = response.read()
start = page.find("all reviews")
link_start = page.find("href=", start) + 6
link_end = page.find('"', link_start)
print page[link_start:link_end]
```

The program should output:
    [http://www.amazon.com/Ole-Henriksen-Truth-Collagen-Booster/product- reviews/B000A0ADT8/ref=dp_top_cm_cr_acr_txt?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1](http://www.amazon.com/Ole-Henriksen-Truth-Collagen-Booster/product-reviews/B000A0ADT8)

Instead, it outputs:
    http://www.amazon.com/Ole-Henriksen-Truth-Collagen-Booster/product-reviews/B000A0ADT8

Comment: I don't even get the substring "show" on the fetched page, so I'm not sure your desired link is necessarily there to be found.  BTW, rather than using `find` this way, you should probably be using BeautifulSoup.  The learning curve is pretty gentle and it makes extracting tags a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check out BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 1):

I get the same result you do, but that appears to be simply because the page Amazon serves to your Python script is different from what it serves to my browser. I wrote the downloaded page to disk and loaded it in a text editor, and sure enough, the link ends with `ADT8"` without all the `/ref=dp_top` stuff.

In order to help convince Amazon to serve you the same page as a browser, your script is probably going to have to act a lot more like a browser (by accepting and sending cookies, for example). The [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) module can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, okay.  If you do the usual trick of faking a user agent, for example:

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.amazon.com/Ole-Henriksen-Truth-Collagen-Booster/dp/B000A0ADT8/ref=sr_1_1?s=hpc&ie=UTF8&qid=1342922857&sr=1-1&keywords=truth')
ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20110506 Firefox/4.0.1'    
req.add_header('User-Agent', ua)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

then you should get something like

```
localhost-2:coding $ python plink.py
http://www.amazon.com/Ole-Henriksen-Truth-Collagen-Booster/product-reviews/B000A0ADT8/ref=dp_top_cm_cr_acr_txt/190-6179299-9485047?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1
```

which might be closer to what you want.

[Disclaimer: be sure to verify that Amazon's TOS rules permit whatever you're going to do before you do it..]